# Geometry nodes - Split Curve with Profile at Angle points (Gaps beetwen curve segments)

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel

Maybe you guys have an idea: how to create gaps on curve with profile between two segments
I think there is only one possible solution: somehow procedurally bevel curve with profile only at curve's angles and then downscale middle cut

I've created template file with an example:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might not be the optimal solution in every case, but in this case it could help you:

Just create cubes at the vertices with the appropriate scaling, change the positions the same as for your mesh, and then use the node `Mesh Boolean` to cut this mesh into several parts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice solution!!!

Comment: @Chris Thank you!